# Matplotlib glitch [python3]

Tags: python-3.x, function, matplotlib, plot

H everyone,
I'm trying to make a simple matplotlib graphic function to represent a capacitor charing and discharging functions. Here is the program:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

import math

x_data = [0] # storing the variable values
y_data = [0] # storing the dependent variable value

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # creating a subplot and its axes
ax.set_xlim(0, 20) # setting the x axe limits
ax.set_ylim(0, 12) # setting the y axe limits
line, = ax.plot(0, 0) # create a line object

# creating an function to animate
def animation_frame(t):

    x_data.append(t) # append the variable to x_data arrya

    # print a sort of differential of the function
    print(y_data[len(y_data) - 1] - y_data[len(y_data) - 2])

    # check if the differential is so small that can be considered as 0 (local maximum point)
    if y_data[len(y_data) - 1] - y_data[len(y_data) - 2] >= 0.0012 or y_data[len(y_data) - 1] - y_data[len(y_data) - 2] == 0.0:

        # if it isn't continue plotting the charging function
        y_data.append(9 * ( 1 - (np.e)**(-(t/(180000*0.00001)))))

    else:
        # plot the discharging function
        y_data.append(9 * (np.e)**(-(t/(180000*0.00001))))

    # set the line points coordinates
    line.set_xdata(x_data)
    line.set_ydata(y_data)

run the animation function 
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation_frame, frames=np.arange(0, 10, 0.05), interval=10)

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

It isn't important the function type, because even if in the else of the if-else clause (in the animate function) I insert a simple identity (f(t) = t), it won't work and it glitches out, here are some images:

[image: Final glitch using the f(t) = t function]

[image: Final glitch using the f(t) = V0 * e^(-t/RC) discharge function]

I suspect that the issue is inside the differential check part, in the animate function... But I don't know how to resolve it.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The diagonal line comes from the animation restarting when `t` gets to 10, but the `xdata` keeps being appended. You could try to set `max_time` higher e.g. `20` in`frames=np.arange(0, max_time, 0.05)`. You can also set `FuncAnimation(..., repeat=False)`. Also, the 'discharging function' could be written as `9 * (np.e)**(-((t-10)/(180000*0.00001)))` to incorporate the time (10) when the discharge starts.

Comment: The best thing you can do, is first just make a full non-animated plot to make sure the curves look as intended.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and your time, I've managed to make it work, thank you again!